# Set the returned data to Kendo Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working in ASP.Net MVC. I have a dropdownlist of Kendo and a form to insert data to database and set the recently inserted data to be selected on kendo dropdown.I am using angular for post method.

```
var response = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: loadAllProductsUrl,
                data: JSON.stringify(customerdetail),
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            });

            $('#customerModal').modal('hide');
            return response.then(function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    $("#customers").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
                    setToDropdown(data);

                }
                else {

                }
            });
```

This is my Post method and from here I return the Customer Code and set it to the kendo dropdownlist.

```
function setToDropdown(data) {

            var temp = $("#customers").data("kendoDropDownList");
              temp.select(function (dataItem) {
                  return dataItem.CustomerCode === data;
              });
        }
```

But the data is not being set to the dropdownlist because setToDropdown(data) is executed before $("#customers").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read(); is loaded fully. Please suggest....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped me

```
 getCustomer(function (a) {

                            setTimeout(function () {

                                $("#customers").data("kendoDropDownList").value(data.CustomerName);
                            }, 100);

                        });
```